# How do I add subtitles to a DVD?

Tags: mac, dvd

I have to do a translation of the words of a DVD, and then add subtitles to that DVD (iso file or folder).

This is a professional work and it has to be clean (no change in quality, ie no "rip"...).

How can I add subtitles to a DVD (file) on a Mac (snow leopard)?

- wysiwyg: being able to view the DVD / stop it to add the subtitle, set the duration easily
- if possibly, set the font, size and position of subtitles
- (if possibly, even add subtitles to the DVD Menu)

Is there already an App on the Mac that does that and just need a download?
Or a 3rd party software is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Final Cut Pro can do that.](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xbci1q_creating-subtitles-in-final-cut-pro_shortfilms.)

[So can DVD Studio Pro.](http://documentation.apple.com/en/dvdstudiopro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=19&section=9&tasks=true)

There are also some free alternatives, most notable: [Aegisub](http://docs.aegisub.org/manual/Attaching_subtitles_to_video) and [Jubler](http://www.jubler.org/features/index.php).

Comment: DVD Studio Pro is really the way to go. +1

Comment: DVD Studio Pro seems to be discontinued. Is there a way to get a clean and safe version? (legally)

Comment: @ring0 - DVD Studio Pro is now being sold as part of Final Cut Pro.

Comment: @ring0 Actually, Final Cut Studio is "discontinued". Apple was still selling it via phone last time I checked, but I'm not sure that they still are.

Comment: @daviesgeek thanks - FCP does *not* do that, FCS (and DVD SP) are discontinued :-(

Answer (score 4):

I would go with DVD Studio Pro.

Basically, you create a subtitle clip and position it:
[image: subtitle clip dvdsp]
Click the textarea in the Inspector, and start typing. You can format the font by bringing up the Fonts window by going to Format > Font > Show Fonts (or pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
[image: Font window]
And that's the basic idea. Pretty simple. You can find [a little more detailed article in Apple's KB.](http://documentation.apple.com/en/dvdstudiopro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=19&section=9&tasks=true)

Comment: Great example of using DVD Studio Pro!

Comment: @Vlad Thanks! However your answer pushed me to get *this* answer up.