# How to play a dvd movie with external subtitles?

Tags: video, dvd, subtitle

This is not about authoring the DVD (not similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/39048/61618)): just want to insert the DVD in a laptop, start it in a video player, and then add a separate subtitle that I have myself found. (Some DVD movies contain no subtitles - or some subtitles may be needed that are not on the DVD.)

I know how to do that [in Windows](https://superuser.com/a/719335/162573) and [in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259729/32012) - without VLC: it can try but has bad results in this respect. - Every time I try it, external subtitle display for a DVD in VLC is erratic; usually subtitles are not always displayed, or they disappear after a while, namely after pause/play or after going back and forth. (See [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=101669), [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=69335), [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=99801&p=335890&hilit=subtitles%20disappear#p335890), [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=53633&p=175627&hilit=subtitles%20disappear#p175627) about this old bug that is not yet completely gone, afaict.) [Here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=101669#p343275) it says VLC is the only Mac player that can do the job. But is it?

Are there some Mac video players that could achieve this task - like MPC-HC (Potplayer, etc) can in Windows (and MPV and SMPlayer in Linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary answer as I don't have a Mac at hand now.

I have to test on a Mac, but the Windows version of [5kPlayer](http://www.5kplayer.com/) can do it very well; and **it has a Mac version**.

Also, KMPlayer can also do it (also tested just in Windows for the moment) and it has a Mac version it seems ([here](http://www.kmplayer.com/) - Mac Alpha Version: have yet to test too).